# ERROR: Failed to remove network for build

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I have installed gitlab-runner via docker in my server with this command:

```
docker exec -it gitlab-runner gitlab-runner register \
--non-interactive \
--url "http://gitlab.aloghesti.local" \
--registration-token "glrt-v5YDsxuazYRUXMXRsuWU" \
--executor "docker" \
--docker-image docker:latest \
--docker-tlsverify="false" \
--docker-privileged="false" \
--docker-volumes='/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock' \
--docker-volumes='/cache' \
--description "aloghesti-runner" \
--tag-list "docker.sock,imac" \
--run-untagged="true" \
--locked="false" \
--access-level="not_protected"
```

But whenever run my jobs I get this error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.5.0 (853330f9)
  on aloghesti-runner v5YDsxuaz, system ID: r_qfj6n9LoVjcy
Preparing the "docker" executor
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: error during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/v1.24/info": dial tcp: lookup docker on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host (docker.go:826:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: error during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/v1.24/info": dial tcp: lookup docker on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host (docker.go:826:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: error during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/v1.24/info": dial tcp: lookup docker on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host (docker.go:826:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): error during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/v1.24/info": dial tcp: lookup docker on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host (docker.go:826:0s)
```

I do not know what is the problem and have searched so much on Google and other Ways.